# Grep a block of text using pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, pattern-matching, regular-language

I have short text file, where i should make output of data using special pattern. My file:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
11 test1
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
17 test1
18 test4
```

One by one, from test1 to test2 and to test3. So... I have written the comand:

```
sed '/test1.*\|test2.*\|test3/!d' filename
```

And in output i have result:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
11 test1
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
17 test1
```

In this case, i have lines, that i not need:

```
11 test1

17 test1
```

This lines don't go one after one. How i can do result, that i need ? Please help me. Thanks for your attention. i Should get this result:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
```

Comment: Did you notice that your question is unclear?

Comment: what are the criteria to determine those lines are not needed?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you need the lines that have a full sequence of `test{1,2,3}` lines and to remove all others? If so: Please add such wording to your question so it becomes clear to other users.

Comment: @sorontar most probably this is what he wants. Keep lines that follow the patter test1-2-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple quick way, although not very elegant, is to put it in one line, break it in the desired pattern, and then filter it again with the pattern:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' < filename | \
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9] test1\\n[0-9][0-9] test2\\n[0-9][0-9] test3\\n\)/\n\1\n/g' | \
egrep "[0-9][0-9] test1\\\n[0-9][0-9] test2\\\n[0-9][0-9] test3\\\n" | \
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | grep .
```

Comment: not bad. but in output, i have:
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3.
but i should have:
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3

Comment: Works as expected for me, maybe you have a different flavour of grep and sed. You should check the output without the last two commands (grep and sed) to see what you get and then work from there.

Comment: in your case, i have output first three lines, but i should get all lines in pattern (test1,test2,test3)